# Get RETURN value from stored procedure in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure where it ends with a RETURN value of 0 or 1.

I want to use this value in an IF statement in another stored procedure.

How can I get the return value of the former stored procedure and save it in a variable in the latter?

I couldn't find anything related. All questions are about fetching the RETURN values in C#.

I was thinking, maybe something like this :

**SP_Two**

```
DECLARE @returnValue INT
SET @returnValue = EXEC SP_One

IF @returnValue = 1
    BEGIN
       --do something
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
       --do something else
    END
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

This should work for you. Infact the one which you are thinking will also work:-

```
 .......
 DECLARE @returnvalue INT

 EXEC @returnvalue = SP_One
 .....
```

Answer (score 28):

The accepted answer is invalid with the double EXEC (only need the first EXEC):

```
DECLARE @returnvalue int;
EXEC @returnvalue = SP_SomeProc
PRINT @returnvalue
```

And you still need to call PRINT (at least in Visual Studio).

Answer (score 10):

Assign after the `EXEC` token:

```
DECLARE @returnValue INT

EXEC @returnValue = SP_One
```