# PHP get return value of stored procedure

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo, sqlsrv

I have pleasure to work with legacy PHP application using SQL Server via PDO.

How in PHP can I retrieve return value of stored procedure which is using [`RETURN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017#returning-data-using-a-return-code) statement as output channel?

Example procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[mleko_test]
    @param INT
AS
  BEGIN
    RETURN @param * 3;
  END
GO
```

If possible, I would prefer to not modify procedure.

---

I am aware that there are similar questions, but they don't cover this case

- [Get RETURN value from stored procedure in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605198/get-return-value-from-stored-procedure-in-sql)
- [Get Return Value from SQL Stored Procedure using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641726/get-return-value-from-sql-stored-procedure-using-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute stored procedure like this: `"exec ?=mleko_test(?)"`.

**Working example:**

```
<?php
#------------------------------
# Connection info
#------------------------------
$server = 'server\instance,port';
$database = 'database';
$uid = 'user';
$pwd = 'password';

#------------------------------
# With PDO
#------------------------------
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;Database=$database", $uid, $pwd);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch ( PDOException $e ) {
    die ( "Error connecting to SQL Server" );
}

try {
    $sql = "exec ? = mleko_test (?)";
    $param = 3;
    $spresult = 0;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $spresult, PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, PDO::SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT_DEFAULT_SIZE);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $param);
    $stmt->execute();
} catch ( PDOException $e ) {
    die ( "Error connecting to SQL Server" );
}

$stmt = null;
$conn = null;

echo 'Stored procedure return value (with PDO): '.$spresult."</br>";

#------------------------------
# Without PDO
#------------------------------
$cinfo = array (
    "Database" => $database,
    "UID" => $uid,
    "PWD" => $pwd
);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
if ( $conn === false )
{
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

$sql = "exec ? = mleko_test (?)";
$param = 3;
$spresult = 0;
$params = array(   
    array(&$spresult, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT), 
    array($param, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),  
); 
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
if ( $stmt === false ) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);

echo 'Stored procedure return value (without PDO): '.$spresult."</br>";
?>
```

**Notes:**

Tested with PHP 7.1.12 and PHP Driver for SQL Server (pdo_sqlsrv version 4.3.0+9904).

Comment: Can you move PDO version higher(as question is mainly PDO related)? Also, why specifying `length` (3rd parameter to bindParam) is mandatory? I tried without it and it didn't worked.

Comment: @mleko I've made some changes using PDO::SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT_DEFAULT_SIZE as $length parameter. I'm more familiar with not PDO version of this driver, but what I've found is that when $length is specified in the bindParam call, the driver interprets it as an indication that you are binding an output (or in-out) parameter. For input-only parameters, there is no need to have a length.

Comment: Ok, great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I came to a solution using multi-query but [@Zhorov answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51588024/3552932) is cleaner

```
<?php
$connection = new PDO($connectionString, $DB_USERNAME, $DB_PASSWORD);

$stmt = $connection->prepare(<<<SQL
DECLARE @a INT;
EXEC @a = mleko_test :in
SELECT @a AS result;
SQL
);

$stmt->execute([":in" => 123]);
echo $stmt->fetch()["result"] . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change

```
$sql = "exec ?=mleko_test(?)";
```

for

```
$sql = "{?=call mleko_test(?)}";
```