# How to store a return result of Function or stored procedure using PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I require some assistance when it comes to storing a result into a PHP variable using PDO by executing a SQL Server stored procedure:

```
protected function checkUser($uid, $password) 
{
      $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare('EXEC spf_SYS_ValidateUser ?,?');
      $stmt->bindParam(1, $uid);
      $stmt->bindParam(2, $password);

      if(!$stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt = null;
        header("location: ../index.php?error=stmtfailed");
        exit();
}
```

What would be my next steps to store the return value of the stored procedure into a PHP variable?

Comment: 1) Store the result from the execution into a variable, 2) Make the appropriate parameter binding, 3) Fetch all possible result sets to make the values of the output parameters available . A similar [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555221/php-get-return-value-of-stored-procedure/51588024#51588024).

Comment: Thank you @Zhorov - I will look into this tonight and give it a try, appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Is it a `RETURN` value, or an `OUTPUT` parameter or a `SELECT`?

Comment: Hi @Charlieface - Either return or output as I would like to return a BIT value of either 1 or 0 (true or false) or at times I would like to return an actual string.

Comment: `RETURN` can only return an integer. Use `bindParam` with `PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT` [as documented](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)